# How to avoid the need for nested calls to Spark dataframes - which dont' work

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Suppose I have a Spark dataframe called `trades` which has in its schema a few columns, some dimensions (let's say *Product* and *Type*) and some facts (let's say *Price* and *Volume*).

Rows in the dataframe which have the same dimension columns belong logically to the same group.

What I need is to map each dimension set (Product, Type) to a numeric value, so to obtain in the end a dataframe `stats` which has as many rows as the distinct number of dimensions and a value - this is the critical part - which is obtained from all the rows in `trades` of that (Product, Type) and which must be computed sequentially in order, because the function applied row by row is neither associative nor commutative, and it cannot be parallelized.

I managed to handle the sequential function I need to apply to each subset by repartitioning to 1 single chunk each dataframe and sorting the rows, so to get exactly what I need.

The thing I am struggling with is how to do the map from `trades` to `stats` as a Spark job: in my scenario master is remote and can leverage multiple executors, while the deploy mode is local and local machine is poorly equipped.
So I don't want to do looping over the driver, but push it down to the cluster.

If this was not Spark, I'd have done something like:

```scala
val dimensions = trades.select("Product", "Type").distinct()
val stats = dimensions.map( row =>
     val product = row.getAs[String]("Product")
     val type = row.getAs[String]("Type")
     val inScope = col("Product") === product and col("Type") === type
     val tradesInScope = trades.filter(inScope)
     Row(product, type, callSequentialFunction(tradesInScope))
)
```

This seemed fine to me, but it's absolutely not working: I am trying to do a nested call on `trades`, and it seem they are not supported. Indeed, when running this the spark job compile but when actually performing an action I get a `NullPointerException` because the dataframe `trades` is null within the `map`

I am new to Spark, and I don't know any other way of achieving the same intent in a valid way. Could you help me?

Comment: To make things maybe more clear, what I actually need is something very very similar to a UDAF for a custom aggregate logic to apply for each dimension. The problem is that I don't know how top make a UDAF work with the sequntial constraint I have

Comment: So you want to run it on the cluster, but still don't want parallelism?

Comment: I need parallelism, because otherwise execution time will be massive. But the function on each dimension is impossible to parallelize, so parallelism can only be achieved for each dimension, not for each row

Answer (score 0):

you get a `NullpointerExecption`because you cannot use dataframes within executor-side code, they only live on the driver.Also, your code would not ensure that`callSequentialFunction`  will be called sequentially, because `map` on a dataframe will run in parallel (if you have more than 1 partition). What you can do is something like this:

```
val dimensions = trades.select("Product", "Type").distinct().as[(String,String)].collect()

val stats = dimensions.map{case (product,type) => 
     val inScope = col("Product") === product and col("Type") === type
     val tradesInScope = trades.filter(inScope)
     (product, type, callSequentialFunction(tradesInScope))
}
```

But note that the order in `dimensions`is somewhat arbitrary, so you should sort `dimensions`according to your needs

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion and explanation. I was guessing that the problem was something like that, but now it's clearer. Just to be , I don't depend on the order in which dimensions are handled, they're completely independent from each other. What needs to be handled sequentially are the tradesInScope used by that function, but that is already handled by ensuring a single partition, and it's stable.

Comment: Anyway, funny enough, that solution you showed me is exactly the workaround I used: I was not completely satisfied because in that way I am relying on the driver to handle parallelism on the dimensions, which is not ideal since it will be having 1 core whilst the cluster like 64